# Webstorm can't find '@angular/core';

Tags: angular, npm

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
or any other module in @angular folder.
```

Those folders **does exsist** but for some reason - webstorm or typescript or something else doesnt find it.

```
im working with angular 2 cli 
node v = 6.2.2
npm v =3.9.5
....
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webstorm :
File->settings->Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript ->enable typescript compiler & Use tsconfig.json

Enjoy :)

Comment: This setting no longer exists in the current versions of WebStorm.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same issue. For me, the solution was to go to file > settings > languages and frameworks > TypeScript: there is a dropdown there next to the text 'TypeScript:' that has paths to all the places that contain node modules that the IDE is aware of. I just added the path to 'node_modules' in my current project and it resolved the imports.

Comment: I had to set this node path to the latest version (node 12), which was just installed automatically due to a yarn update.